# Including PHP Class in Magento 2 Controller

Tags: magento2, composer

I have this 3rd party class Mailchimp.php which I need to include in my controller so that I can create an object and make api calls. But I'm not able to do so. I get this error when I try to run my controller.

Class 'Mailchimp' not found in /var/www/html/magentotwo/app/code/Vss/Mailchimp/Controller/Index/Add.php

I've installed mailchimp through composer through following command

> composer require drewm/mailchimp-api

and can find the library in my magento's vendor folder.

Following is the code of my controller:

```
<?php

namespace Vss\Mailchimp\Controller\Index;

use Mailchimp;




class Add extends \Vss\Mailchimp\Controller\Index\Index
{


    public function execute()
    {
        $api_key = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('mailchimp/apikey/api_key_frontend', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        $MailChimp = new Mailchimp($api_key);
        $result = $MailChimp->get('lists');
        print_r($result);
    }
}
?>
```

Following is the folder structure of library installed
[image]

Please tell me how to proceed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api
you should use

```
use \DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp;
```

And you can test following way

```
$MailChimp = new MailChimp('abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123-us1');
$result = $MailChimp->get('lists');

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Yes. But it worked with use MailChimp\MailChimp; instead. Thanks.